# How to add section in NavigationView On material design

Tags: android, material-design, navigationview

i need to have two beautifull section like this library in My `NavigationView` `Drawer.xml`

exactly like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbhzu.jpg

i'm currently using this:

https://github.com/AkashBang/NavigationView

How we can do that?

Answer (score 1):

solved, Here is the example:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuItem1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
        android:title="MenuItem 1" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuItem2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
        android:title="MenuItem 2" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuItem3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_headset"
        android:title="MenuItem 3" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuItem4"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
        android:title="MenuItem 4" />
</group>

<item android:title="Sub items" >
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuItem5"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="Sub item 5" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuItem6"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_forum"
            android:title="Sub item 6" />
    </menu>
</item>
```